# username and pass login loop bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

the loop gets initiated even though the if statement does as well which makes no sense, but i am very new to bash so not a lot of things make sense to me

```
first=0
echo enter your username
read user
log1=$(grep -q $user username_pass.txt)

echo enter your password
read pass
log2=$(grep -q $pass username_pass.txt )

if [ $log1=0 ] && [ $log2=0 ];
then
    echo Welcome
    first=1
fi 

while [ $log1=1 ] || [ $log2=1 ];
do 
    echo wrong user name or password
    echo enter your username
    read user
    echo enter your password
    read pass
done

if [ $log1=0 ] && [ $log2=0 ] && [ first=0 ];
then
    echo Welcome
fi
```

Comment: Which `if` statement? Your question is unclear.

Comment: this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442693/username-password-program-in-bash

Comment: its not a duplicate its a different question on a different part of the code

Answer (score 0):

`[ … ]` is not particularly special syntax in shells. You’re passing arguments `$log1=0` and `]` to a command called `[`, which removes the `]` from its arguments and passes the rest to `test`. Supposing `$log1` contains “username”, the result is:

```
test 'username=0'
```

When `test` gets one argument, it checks if that argument is a non-empty string. `$log1=0` will never be an empty string.

What you’re really looking for is to pass the operator and operands as separate arguments, like this:

```
if [ "$log1" = 0 ] && [ "$log2" = 0 ]; then
```

Note the quotes, which prevent `$log1` from being expanded to more than one argument.

You also probably meant to get an exit code from `grep` instead of the output if you’re comparing it against a number, which would be `$?` after running the command:

```
grep -q "$user" username_pass.txt
log1=$?
```

You could also split this out into a function for ease of use.

```
test_credentials() {
    grep -q "$1" username_pass.txt || return 1
    grep -q "$2" username_pass.txt || return 1
}

if test_credentials "$user" "$pass"; then
    …
```

You might also want to rethink how you’re checking credentials. grepping the same file twice could have many problems, but one problem it *definitely* has is that you can log in by using the username as the password.

Comment: i have a file with 2 columns one is usernames and the other is passwords, they are input by the user in a different part of the code not shown, i want it so that it checks that the username and the password they input matches any of the usernames and passwords in the file named username_pass.txt

Comment: @AdrianFall: Great! And?

Comment: is there any way to use awk to find where the username is and check if the second input matches the password in the second column of that line?